# 503 Login WordPress

Tags: login

Anyone have experience failed to login and got the 503 Service Unvailable?

My WP site hosted on GoDaddy Managed Hosting. They said cause of this is came from the WooCommerce. I tried to disable this but the error still occured.

Thanks

Comment: This is a godaddy issue. Please see http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E503.html for the http code and what it means.

Comment: I thought also the server issues, this problem not regularly came out, if they said cause the plugin when disabled/not. The page can not be accesed regularly because the plugin still active. Or is it possible this is cause by Google Translate scripts? I tested with pingdom and this scripts hight loaded than others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had 503 errors when using shared hosting services with Fasthosts / Rackspace etc.  Typically, they don't last long, but if yours are - then there is something going on with the server you are sharing.  You might want to check that the memory limit in the config is 96 MB but that shouldn't be causing the issue.